# Escape values of a JSON String without breaking the JSON

Tags: java, json, escaping, gson

I'm trying to escape the values from a JSON-String and remove HTML chars (Like "<script>" etc.) in the backend. I've read that GSON normaly does that itself but in my case not because I'm directly filling the javaobject via "fromJson".

If I'm just using the commons library and escape with escapeString or escapeJson it will also escape the double quotes (") and will break then the fromJson function from GSON.

I'm using following functionality to fill the Object:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").create();
DataObject dObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, DataObject.class);
```

The json string looks like following (is dynamic):

```
{"dynamic":[
     {"id":1,"constrain":"1","value_text":"test"},
     {"id":11,"constrain":"1","value_boolean":1},
     ],"name":"Xzzz",
       "prename":"XY",
       "language":"e",
       "email":"x@xy.com"
}
```

I just want to escape the values of the json string (Like when someone types as name "<script>" it should be escaped as &lt ;script&gt ;)

Has anyone any idea how I could fix that problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you are trying to sanitize the user's input to prevent cross-site scripting.
What you probably want to do is use a whitelist for input allowed. Once the input passes you can send it to the backend.

this is a good reference

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer

summarized it boils down to this:

```
String unsafe = 
"<p><a href='http://example.com/' onclick='stealCookies()'>Link</a></p>";
String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());
// now: <p><a href="http://example.com/" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed it now with using Jsoup to clean the json-string from all html tags and then after that (because Jsoup will escape all quotes with &quot;) "unescapeHtml4" from apache common langs so the json is valid again after that. thanks

Comment: with this kind of json `{"key":"<img src=a onerror=alert(456)> "}` it doesn't works. `Jsoup.clean` then `unescapeHtml4` because the produced result is `{"key":"<img src="a"> "}` : invalid json. any idea ?

Comment: @herau After Jsoup clean I call `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(my_jsouped_string)`

Answer (score 1):

If the content if the Json is correct json you should not worry about html encoding. Any json library will not have automatic html encoding for attributes. 
If you need to encode as html you can use this lib: http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html#encodeForHTML(java.lang.String)

If you want to encode for an html attribute assignation (a likely scenario also) you should use this instead:
http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html#encodeForHTMLAttribute(java.lang.String)

my advice is that after any of this encoding you apply:http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html#encodeForJavaScript(java.lang.String) if your library does not provide this.

In general when encode you have to know how the parsers (Javascript/json/html) in the browser run and in which order.

Comment: if i try your solution, the result isn't a valid JSON. Does your solution require a specific configuration of ESAPI to works ?

Comment: It should not. Should be something like: ESAPI.encodeForJavaScript(ESAPI.encodeForHTML(input)) or ESAPI.encodeForJavaScript(ESAPI.encodeForHTMLAttribute(input)) and put inside "" if you create JSON by concatenating "manually" to create valid JSON.

Comment: i'm not sure to understand your explanation. if i have a valid JSON as input of the `encodeForHtml()` method, the produced result isn't a valid JSON (even if it wrapped around of `encodeForJavascript()`)